# Can I update all my posts inside my custom post type by creating a simple function

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm stuck at a scenario where my events custom post type posts have categories ticked but not actually assigned to them untill I manually republish or update every single post.

And its happening accros multisites and there are thousand of events which I cannot update manually one by one.

I was thinking of using wp-insert-post or wp-update-post functionality of wordpress in a loop across all my custom post type posts...

If anyone can point me in right direction.

Regards.

Comment: you can use [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) to retrieve all posts of a custom post type and loop across all of them.

Comment: if the categories are ticked that means they're assigned, what's the root problem you're trying to solve that lead you to the theory that the categories aren't assigned?

Comment: Well in my case the categories are used to show different colors for different categories, but after some updates the colors are not showing on my front end calender.

Comment: But when I go in backend of any event post the catgory ticks are marked but not actually assigned to the post, and when I open and republish post without any changes at all it saves the category already ticked and shows up fine on front end calender... lemme know if you need further clarification and I'll share screenshots of whats happening...